# Onclick image how to open corresponding video to that image for dynamic data in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have multiple images on 1 page, when click on particular image , video will open corresponding to that image on next page. Currently I have same id's for all image so I am not able to understand what to do to open that video on next page corresponding to image.
I am using below data:
 `[ [ 123, "thumb.jpg", "09-50-01.09-55-01.a-123-out.avi", ], [ 123, "thumb.jpg", "14-00-01.14-05-01.A-123-out.avi", ], [ 123, "thumb.jpg", "17-00-06.17-05-06.A-123-out.avi", ], [ 123, "thumb.jpg", "17-05-06.17-10-06.A-123-out.avi", ], [ 123, "thumb.jpg", "17-10-06.17-15-06.A-123-out.avi", ], [ 123, "thumb.jpg", "17-35-06.17-40-06.A-123-out.avi", ] ]`
Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you can do if your video is on the next page, provide the ID in the route then the ID with a subscription.

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {}

setupSubscriptions() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
     if (params.videoId) {
       //Your logic to play the video here
     }
   });
 )
```

Obviously you also need to pass unique id's and if this is not possible you can pass the video name in the route data.

And dont forget to call setupSubscriptions() in your ngOninit

Comment: How can I use queryParams in this case?

Comment: Because I have to make url to redirect to other page like localhost:4200/app/123/(queryParams) here I can pass query params to get that particular video of particular image.. so i just want to know how can I pass in url so that I'll go to other based on those parameters